# How I submit my glass app in google glass

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I build a glass app using mirror api. Now I want to submit in google that any one can download my app from glassware.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use this link,might be helpful   http://www.seroundtable.com/google-glass-app-distribution-17470.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to have your Glassware listed on [MyGlass](http://google.com/myglass). Follow these steps:

1. Ensure that your Glassware adheres to all of the guidelines provided in the official documentation. Google provides a [checklist](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/checklist) that you can use.
2. Prepare icons and assets that will appear on Glass and MyGlass. There's a list of the icons to create [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/checklist#provide_assets_for_myglass).
3. Fill out the [distribution form](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/form) to initiate the review process.
4. If you'd like to use any new voice commands from the "ok glass" menu, request these in a [separate form](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form).

Comment: Thanks Jenny, I will follow the steps

Comment: i have an application that uses GDK Authentication that I need to test before I actually roll it out. In that case where should I mention it in the form. Since I am testing is there any limit to the number of times I upload the apk

Comment: There's a free form field at the end. Mention it there. And no, there's no limit to the iterations of your APK.